# What is the difference between Meniere's disease and Meniere's syndrome?

Tags: menieres-disease

What is the difference between Meniere's disease and Meniere's syndrome? Is there any difference between the symptoms?

Comment: Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require prior research information when asking questions. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is the difference between Meniere's disease and Meniere's
> syndrome? Is there any difference between the symptoms?

Merriam-Webster defines [*Disease*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disease) as:

> 1 : a condition of the living animal or plant body or of one of its
> parts that impairs normal functioning and is typically manifested by
> distinguishing signs and symptoms.

and it defines [*Syndrome*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/syndrome) as:

> 1 : a group of signs and symptoms that occur together and characterize
> a particular abnormality or condition
>
> 2 : a set of concurrent things (such as emotions or actions) that
> usually form an identifiable pattern

To expand upon the basic framework supplied by the dictionary, [medscape.com](https://emedicine.medscape.com/article/1159069-overview) clarifies matters:

> Ménière disease is endolymphatic hydrops of unknown etiology (ie,
> idiopathic endolymphatic hydrops). [**Making it the primary condition.**]
>
> Ménière syndrome is endolymphatic hydrops caused by a specific
> condition. [**ie. by any of a number of known primary causes, making the syndrome secondary as such.**]
>
> ...both of which are both believed [**sic**] to result from increased pressure
> within the endolymphatic system.
>
> However, Ménière disease is idiopathic by definition, whereas Ménière
> syndrome can occur secondary to various processes interfering with
> normal production or resorption of endolymph.

[*Words in bold - mine.*]

It is the focus of close attention:

> With the growing understanding of the pathophysiology and disease
> processes involved with Ménière disease a re-evaluation and possible
> redefinition of this condition are well underway.

Edited: By suggestion of Jan.

Comment: @Jan Your comment sounds like the basis of a more strictly correct answer than mine, but it raises the point of usage of the terms if overdiagnosis (ie. cryptic misdiagnosis) is occuring to a great degree as the 2nd article indicates.

Comment: @Jan I understand the distinction and your point and will edit the answer accordingly, my point was - not important, more to do with my pet peeves than the question.

Comment: thank you very much for the detailed answer! Please excuse me if this question is apparent for a person with a medical background as I have no such background. Kind regards, Marchev!

Comment: @Marchev You are welcome, it's always ok to ask.

Answer (score 2):

Basically the disease is the ailment  Currently, the etiology (cause or underlying pathophysiology) of that ailment is still being researched and defined.  But the disease is not a symptom of another disease process. 
The syndrome is exactly that.  A person has a disease with symptoms that are the same as the disease or highly similar,  but the cause of those symptoms are actually another disease process. 
I wasn't trying to be condescending.  I just feel like I tried to explain in the simplest terms which made it a long and convoluted explanation. 
Do you understand?